# Angular 2+ issue in IE(9+)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular5

Angular 2+(6) application is not working in IE after enabling all suggested polyfills for both development and production environment (deployed in **Intranet** environment). I understand this question has been asked many times but they are not helpful.

I have done all the possible work around available on internet.

**IE 9+ Console error:** (I have tried adding compatibility view as well though it is not an good idea)

[image]

**BROWSER POLYFILLS** ran the required commands too (web animation and classlist)

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;


 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bom-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "angular2-swiper": "^0.8.1",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.12",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "swiper": "^4.4.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

**angular.json(cli)**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "bomApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "build",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [              
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
              "node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",          
              "node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js",
              "node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "bomApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "bomApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "bomApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bomApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "bomApp:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "bomApp"
}
```

**tsconfig.json** target is already set as **es5** (suggested by many on internet)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Angular version (ng --version)**

[image]

**index.html** (added meta tag as suggested by many)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>app title</title>

  <base href="/">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/res/images/icons/logo.png">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any useful information will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you open vendor.js, what is around the 139973th character? I think one of the script in your angular.json file (or included somewhere else?) is probably using ES6 syntax (ie: let), so would need to find the proper file to include. You might have trouble figuring out from which original script the code came from - sourcemaps can help with that

Comment: any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by adding the swiper js file in index.html file and remove the angular2 swiper third party plugin,

use this example: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/CharmLuu/pen/KWKdEX)

Swiper js link : [swiper.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nolimits4web/swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.min.js) and add swiper css also.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $, Swiper: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-view',
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swiper.component.css']

})
   export class SwiperDemo implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
   ngOnInit(){
   }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
              new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerGroup: 1,
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                loop: false,
                loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
                pagination: { el: '.swiper-pagination', clickable: true },
                navigation: {
                  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
                }
              });
          });
      }
   }
```

Html:

```
 <div class="container">   
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>

        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```